# How do I apply a diff or patch file?

Tags: ruby, git, patch, rugged

when using the rugged git library how can I apply that diff to my dest branch as a commit?.

```
  # @param src [Rugged::Object] - the rugged object or string to compare from
  # @param dst [Rugged::Object] - the rugged object or string to compare to, defaults to parent
  # @return [Rugged::Diff] a rugged diff object between src and dst
  def create_diff(src, dst = nil)
    src = repo.lookup(find_ref(src))
    dst ||= repo.lookup(src.parents.first)
    dst = find_ref(dst)
    src.diff(dst)
  end

  # @param sha_or_ref [String] - the name or sha of the ref
  # @return [String] the oid of the sha or ref
  def find_ref(sha_or_ref)
    case sha_or_ref
      when Rugged::Object
        sha_or_ref.oid
      else
        repo.rev_parse_oid(sha_or_ref)
    end
  end
```

Is there not an easy way to apply a patch or diff?  Seems silly that I would need to loop through each change in the diff and either add/rm the file.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the:

- [libgit2/rugged is the ruby bindings to libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged)
- libgit2's apply patch feature was requested [from a long time (2013)](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/1980) and only [recently merged (a year ago)](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/3223) for [libgit2 0.24.4](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/20302aa43738a972e0bd2e2ee6ae479208427b31),

You would have to wait for that feature to be ported in rugged.
The last [official release v0.24.0](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/releases/tag/v0.24.0) does not include 0.24.4.

Comment: Over 5 years later, I wonder if this is possible yet

Comment: @MikeSlinn Maybe not in libgit2, but it seems present with [Rust '`git2-rs`'](https://github.com/rust-lang/git2-rs/pull/531)